# Autoresize UICollectionViewCell size inside UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am trying to create simple educational app about movies, and I need to create movie frames horizontal scroller.

I create collection view for that: [image]

But if I build it for another target (iPhone 6s Plus for example), I have this:
[image]

**How to solve this problem?**

My scene controller code **(Swift 3)**:

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    // Configure the cell
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: what is the issue? :)

Comment: I want a cell took all the space of collectionView, from one side of the screen to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can try to implement the method of UICollectionView delegate:

```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(yourHeight, self.view.frame.size.width)
}
```

in this way, your collectionView-cell inside in tableView will appear as big as the screen.

Comment: I add this code:     
`public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        return CGSize.init(width: 600, height: 500)
    }`

and it doesn't work.

Comment: are you initialize the delegate of your UICollectionView ?
sorry for the stupid question but something happen :)

Comment: ok, use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout delegate in your controller.

Comment: Thank you, it's work now. Last thing - how can I get CGSize of the specified TableView cell?

Comment: you can set the height of cell using delegate method of UITableView: 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat

in this way the height of cell is certainly that returned from delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

First I want to say something about UITableViewAutomaticDimension you use, in case you not exactly understand how it works.

Your expectations probably are, that UITableViewAutomaticDimension will infer tableView to make a cell with size of entire tableView, but it doesn't work this way.

UITableViewAutomaticDimension is just infers tableView, that inner size of your cell will be used as a returned here; so if you add some constraints, views with constraints, or whatever inside your tV, its size will be used.

and second - your comment doesn't make sense at all for me, because your posted code isn't related to cell of collectionView and I can't comment anything related to size of its cells

EDITED:

to make all cells with width of your screen, return correct size from delegate method of collectionViewFlowLayout - sizeForItem